# Quorum, where to start?

Tags: quorum

I am relatively new to Ethereum, and i want to know exactly how to migrate to quorum. And by that i mean migrate exisiting contracts.

I also want to know about the how to start with quorum and if there are any tutorials, outside the official ones, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Quorum is an Ethereum-based distributed ledger protocol with transaction/contract privacy and new consensus mechanisms. Quorum is modified version of geth node.

For more details refer below links:

[Quorum GITHub](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum)

[Quorum Overview](https://blockchainatberkeley.blog/introduction-to-quorum-blockchain-for-the-financial-sector-58813f84e88c)

[Truffle for Quorum](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/building-dapps-for-quorum-private-enterprise-blockchains)

[Blockchain tech: Quorum](https://hackernoon.com/choosing-private-blockchain-tech-quorum-d33221d40b54)